# CSS Changing Font Color of a label (before & after span.text-inner)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

Needing help to add custom font color to a form label in CSS to a WordPress site. I have tried adding new style using most of the `selectors` and haven't been successful, it seems something is overriding it. Site: reliableconcreting.com.au

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06wVZ.png)

[When changing the color as per answers below it turns orange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wLI1l.png)

Working in browser not in child css sheet:

```
body[data-form-style="minimal"] .minimal-form-input label span.text .text-inner     {
    color: #000000!important;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Post complete code

Answer (score 0):

You can use !important after your color declaration to override any default colors.

```
.text-inner {
     color: "yourColor" !important;
}
```

Comment: @Jemma Did you make sure to include a space between the color name and !important? e.g. #123456 !important not #123456!important

Comment: @Jemma Another trick I sometimes use if I can't get a style to apply properly is to add an asterisk (*) after the class name. For example:
     
    .text-inner * { color: yourColor !important; }
    
This will apply the style to **all** children of the parent element, so if there is some element that is overruling your style, this will overwrite those elements.

Comment: Thanks adapap really appreciate the help! Still nothing though and no clue why

Answer (score 0):

**important** declaration will override an author rule with a normal declaration.

```css
p{
color: red !important;
}
p{
color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>This is some text.</p>
```

Even i write a new rule after the first one **important** rule will be weighted more and used as a first preference.

Comment: @Jemma  if you can find the span use this way: <span class="text-inner" style="color:red !important">

Comment: Okay thanks for help! @berkay kılıç

I found something that works in browser but not when added to the child css sheet - added above in topic